# Mid sentence insertion in the English Language, does it exist or not?

Tags: grammar

I have been having quite a bit of debate with someone about inserting a slight digression in the middle of a sentence. My native language is Turkish and in the literary sense we use it quite often such as this mot à mot translation;

> In London, where diverse cultures meet, which neighbourhood do you
>   prefer to live in?

A trained translator told me that in Turkish you can insert a sentence with different subject between commas and go on about your main subject, but using this in English is not proper. Is that so, or can I use commas to mention an off-topic subject in the mid-sentence?

So should I have written like something "Where would you like to live in London where diverse cultures meet?"

---

*NB My sentences are short as this is about a twitter post which has a 140 character limit, and I also want to add hashtags and links etc.*

Comment: It's unclear to me, based on the question as it is currently written, what you're asking.

Comment: Definitely add _in_ after _live_ because you can't _live a neighborhood_, you _live in a neighborhood_.

Comment: One can digress in a longer speech or conversation (that is, wander off the point), but I don't understand what you mean by digression in a single sentence.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I think you're using *digression* to mean a brief parenthetical insertion which is not directly relevant to the main point but interesting nonetheless (that is, the extra information "where diverse cultures meet" in your sentence). That's not called *digression,* which is wandering off the subject entirely. Unfortunately, this has made the question unclear. If it's appropriate to change *digression* to *insertion* (if that is in fact what you're asking about) then I'd give this question an upvote.

Comment: For the moment, I'll put this on hold. Please do [edit it](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/397799/edit) to make clear exactly what you are referring to as "digression" and either @comment me or flag for reopening when it's ready.

Comment: Interesting crosslinguistic question. It's hard here to differentiate grammar and style.

Comment: Does it exist?  yes.   Should it be used?  Only if it is not confusing.  (And if you have little experience with English, you may not be able to judge whether it would be confusing.)

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387530/how-to-punctuate-interpolated-interjections-which-are-sentences/387540#387540

Comment: Not only this is the most knowledgeable answer on stackexchange I have ever seen, from now on I won't be able to enjoy answers of IT GODS around here in the IT forums (by the way, I learned English from the movies and I translate social media texts for the beer money :D I'm actually an engineer)

Thank you!